# .htaccess to rewrite to sub directory - preserving page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My directory setup is as follows:

Root directory at **what.ever.ip** (**/var/www/**)

User's sites are **what.ever.ip/username**

Users root ftp are **/var/www/username/upload_files_here**,
which translates to **what.ever.ip/username/upload_files_here**

So if user Foo uploads the file index.html he'll have to visit **what.ever.ip/Foo/upload_files_here/index.html**

I want to use apache .htaccess to rewrite this (without redirecting aka showing it) to display as **what.ever.ip/Foo/index.html**

I have tried multiple solutions without finding one that solve my problem.

So my question is how do I rewrite "**what.ever.ip/username/upload_files_here/index.html**" to "**what.ever.ip/username/index.html**" **without showing it**?

PS. The what.ever.ip is **not known**, could be an **local** address, **localhost** or an **remote** address. So I would prefer a possible wildcard instead of hard coding in "what.ever.ip"

Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in `/var/www/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/((?!upload_files_here/).*)$ /$1/upload_files_here/$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: As long as I feed the url a filename it works, ie. example.com/user/index.html or example.com/user/file.exe
But when I only provide the url example.com/user it goes to that directory instead of the upload_files_here directory. Any fixes?

Comment: See update and make sure there is a trailing slash in `example.com/user/`

Comment: Just to be difficult, this rewrites my ErrorDocuments as well (absolute paths) so instead of /error/404.html it says /error/upload_files_here, is there a RewriteCond we can apply or can I simply only use one of these?

Comment: Great!

If you know, for the errordocuments do I have to user absolute paths? Ie stylesheet links with the href "./style" won't work.

Comment: Always use absolute paths for css/js/image/errordocument i.e. path starting with `/`

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/upload_files_here/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

should change:

`what.ever.ip/username/upload_files_here/index.html` to `what.ever.ip/username/index.html` while showing still `what.ever.ip/username/upload_files_here/index.html` in the URL bar.